# iOS : zoom in and zoom out effect on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, mapkit, zooming

I have created map as show on [this link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/) and its working perfectly.

But the problem is, It only zoom in one way (it get bigger only). How could I make it working on either way?

May be like we have on [google map](https://maps.google.com/) (plus - minus stick on the left side).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ZoomIn

```
-(void)zoomIn
{
    region.span.latitudeDelta = region.span.latitudeDelta/4 ;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = region.span.longitudeDelta/4;



    region.center.latitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude ;
    region.center.longitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude ;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

For ZoomOut

```
-(void)zoomOut
{
    region.span.latitudeDelta = region.span.latitudeDelta*4 ;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = region.span.longitudeDelta*4;



    region.center.latitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude ;
    region.center.longitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude ;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

> **You use the delta values in this structure to indicate the desired
>   zoom level of the map, with smaller delta values corresponding to a
>   higher zoom level.**

Please refer this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html) for more.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will look into it and get back to you incase of any query.

Comment: I added this code and made region variable as global variable `MapViewController { MKCoordinateRegion region; }` and changed `MKCoordinateRegion region = {cords,span};` to `region = {cords,span};`. But I red warning at `region = {cords,span};` as `Expected expression`. What I am missing?

Comment: Also get error at `region.span.latitudeDelta` as `Member reference type 'MKCoordinateRegion *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use '->'?`

Comment: @FahimParkar: you declared region as `MKCoordinateRegion region;` that's the issue. declare it as `MKCoordinateRegion *region;`

Comment: I changed it to `region = (MKCoordinateRegion) {cords,span};` and it worked.

Comment: thanks for the post, can we use a scroll bar as in google maps

Comment: @chandru: Currently I think there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a revision of the answer by Midhun VP and Slavco Petkovski that avoids an NSInvalidArgumentException for an "Invalid Region" in zoomOut when setting the latitudeDelta too large.  Zooming in doesn't seem to have any problems--it just doesn't zoom in any more once it hits the limit.

```
- (void)zoomIn {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = [self.mapView region];
    region.span.latitudeDelta = region.span.latitudeDelta/4;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = region.span.longitudeDelta/4;
    region.center.latitude = self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    //NSLog(@"zoomIn: center %lf, %lf; spanDelta %lf, %lf, upper left %lf, %lf; lower right %lf %lf", region.center.latitude, region.center.longitude, region.span.latitudeDelta, region.span.longitudeDelta, region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta / 2, region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, region.center.longitude + region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);
}

- (void)zoomOut {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = [self.mapView region];
    region.span.latitudeDelta = region.span.latitudeDelta*4;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = region.span.longitudeDelta*4;
    region.center.latitude = self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude;

    // The region upper latitude must not exceed 90.0 degrees, and the region lower latitude must not fall below -90.0.
    double upperLatitude = region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta / 2.0;
    double lowerLatitude = region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta / 2.0;
    if ( upperLatitude > 90 || lowerLatitude < -90 ) {
        region.center.latitude = 0.0;
        double spanRatio = region.span.latitudeDelta / region.span.longitudeDelta;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 180;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 180 / spanRatio;
    }
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    //NSLog(@"zoomOut: center %lf, %lf; spanDelta %lf, %lf, upper left %lf, %lf; lower right %lf %lf", region.center.latitude, region.center.longitude, region.span.latitudeDelta, region.span.longitudeDelta, region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta / 2, region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, region.center.longitude + region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);
}
```

Comment: validation is from our end, answers will not include everything from A-Z.